# Create Folders out of PDF-Names, crop the foldername and move them into the folder

Tags: c#

I want to create a program that gets all the .pdf-filenames (ex: test.pdf -> test) and creates an folder with that name. Also the foldername should be cropped after the first "-" (ex: A539B2AA3-GG-81234278 -> A539B2AA3).

This is the code I have made yet, but I have no clue how to proceed. I'm still a beginner, trying to learn C#:

```cs
string path = @"C:\pdfs\";
string[] filenames;
int lengtharray;

filenames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(s => (Path.GetExtension(s).ToLower() == ".pdf")).ToArray();

lengtharray = filenames.Length;
```

If someone can help me, I would be very happy.

Sincerely,
breadhead

Comment: So now you need to loop through all the filenames. Within the loop, split the filename string using `-` and just use the first element returned from the array (produced by split) as the folder name. Use that to create a new folder. Then move the file into the folder. That should be the procedure. Each of those small steps is fairly easy to research online. Try it out - that's the best way to learn, anyway. If you get stuck on a specific part, ask us about that exact problem.

Comment: @TWP - you should submit that as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

1) `Directory.GetFiles` has a wildcard support, so you can use *.pdf to search for file.

2) I added some validation in the loop, in case there are PDF file that does not have -.

```cs
string path = @"C:\pdfs\";

foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    var newName = Path.GetFileName(file).Split('-');
    if (!newName.Any())
        continue;

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path,newName[0]));
}
```

Comment: I forgot the add that the .pdf needs to be moved into that folder. I tried:                             ```string path2 = path + newName[0];
File.Move(path + Path.GetFileName(file), path2);```

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't seem to work. Tried probaly everything, File.Move doesn't seem to work, do you have an suggestion? :/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your file query, use `filenames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pdf", ....` and skip the Where()-part. To loop through your list, you can use a `foreach (file in filenames)`. As mentioned you can get the new filename with `file.Split("-")[0]` or with a regular expression. Then create a directory with `Directory.CreateDirectory` and move the file in with `System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");`. Now you have all the bricks and you only need to glue them together